# excel function to sum from match list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to get a sum of a range of cells where a corresponding column matches a certain string.

The current function I have is below, which isn't working as desired.

`=IFERROR(SUM(INDEX('DEC 2018'!$G$7:$G$1000,MATCH(C26,'DEC 2018'!$E$7:$E$1000,0))),"")`

Opening the "Current Spreadsheet" image below as an example, in Cell D26 (just for this example for help, not in the finished product) I want the SUM of values from column G, but only including values if the corresponding text in Column E matches the text in Cell C26.

For a value of "Discounted Rate 2" in C26, my function above shows a result of "50", but should be "150", which would be the SUM of the 3 records that are "Discounted Rate 2"

Thank you in advance for your help!

[CurrentSpreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAWwU.png)

Comment: Have you tried sumifs() ?

Comment: I have not. I am not aware of sumif().  I'll check that out now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `=SUMIF($E:$E,C26,$G:$G)` in D26

SUMIF takes the column/range you are wanting to match as the 1st parameter, the 2nd parameter is the value you want to match and the 3rd parameter is the column you want to SUM where the criteria is matched.

You can adjust the absolute references on the columns/ranges if you need to relocate where the formula goes, but this should give you the result you are describing.

Comment: Thank you so much! So much simpler than what I was trying to do  :)  And thank you @SolarMike--He gave the answer as I was looking up your suggestion.